# MetricBeat kubernetes.apiserver: error getting metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, rbac, metricbeat, typhoon-kubernetes

We deployed the metricbeat on our Kubernetes cluster. All the metrics are been pushed to the elasticsearch index without any issues. But observing below error in the metribeat logs and not sure what exactly is causing this.

```sh
2020-07-01T14:05:25.421Z     INFO    module/wrapper.go:259   Error fetching data for metricset kubernetes.apiserver: error getting metrics: unexpected status code 403 from server
```

We have explored and tried the suggested cluster-role and didn't see any success. Below is the cluster-role we are using.

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
      - "apps"
      - "v1"
      - ""
    resources:
      - namespaces
      - pods
      - events
      - deployments
      - nodes
      - replicasets
      - statefulsets
      - nodes/metrics
      - nodes/stats
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
```

Let me know if anyone has came across the same and have fixed it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also show the configuration of the Kubernetes `apiserver` metricset?

Comment: if you don't mind, could you please elaborate what exactly you want me to share..I didn't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm interested in the `ConfigMap` section where you define the content of the `kubernetes.yml` module configuration.

Comment: I pushed the code in [github](https://github.com/vamshisiddarth/elastic-metricbeat-issue). Please check and let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Metricbeat cannot connect to the K8S API server, HTTP 403 is a security error.

According to [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-kubernetes-apiserver.html), can you make sure that you add these in the ClusterRole rules:

```
rules:
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /metrics
  verbs:
  - get
```

Comment: Awesome...this fixed my issue. Thanks a lot Val.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind cloud you please check this as well [other issue](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/metricbeat-unknown-or-unexpected-state-p-for-process-with-pid-25/239512). Appreciate the quick response :)